# troube with iis(maybe)

Tags: c#, iis, configuration

I have a web service on iis that i'm calling in a simple console app
this web service is takes stuff out of a database
I changed the data base on a config file but it seems to still be calling the former data base
any tip?

Comment: Perhaps a little punctuation now and then as a courtesy to your prospective helpers?

Answer (score 1):

If there are some cached database credentials within the application, simply recycling the application pool for which it is in will flush that out. If you're not familiar with the application pools, simply restart IIS and that will do the same thing.

If you don't have credentials cached, could you specify where the credentials are being stored, such as a web.config file, custom library, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the connection string is actually being used rather than it using the settings from the original dataset designer.

If you have used the dataset designer there will be a connection string setting in the settings file of the project. unless the connection string in your web.config is exactly the same then it will use the original.

You can check whether it is using the string you supplied by entering garbage in the web.config connection string and seeing if the webservice fails after you have restarted the website.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to offer this advice without sounding unhelpful, but in cases like these you just have to track through it, logging out the various important bits, like what connection string your components are using when they connect to the database, etc, and the answer will sooner or later come to light. I say this from experience.

There's not much that myself or other posters here can do but offer you the most general advice, like recycling the application pools. Your question is just too short and lacking in information, and the subject of web services is a very wide one.

So start by adding logging as I suggested and it might just work, or at least give us more to go on. All the best to you..

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the connection string in the client app.config or the web services web.config?

Comment: i'm setting the connection on the server side, in a xml document
(the web service has a business layer under it), i tryed to restart iis but it doesn't seem to work.